# add file without full path in zipfolder using SharpZibLib in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharpziplib

File can add with full path easily like :

```
 z.Add(fpaths);
```

But i wants to add only file not full path use code below but a error :

```
 z.Add(fpaths, filenamed); error is! some invalid arguments
```

Please have a look my code and let me know how can i manage this code

```
protected void btnAcceptAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int count = 0;
    string msg = string.Empty;
    string filenamezip = "FileFolder\\FilesZip.zip";
    string strPathAndQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
    string paths = strPathAndQuery + filenamezip;
    ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(paths);
    z.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gv.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
        {
            count++;
            string dirPath = gv.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values[3].ToString();
            string fileName = gv.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
            string filePath = dirPath + "/" + fileName;
            string fpaths = strPathAndQuery + filePath;
            string filenamed = Path.GetFileName(fpaths);
            z.Add(fpaths, filenamed);  //show error
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        z.CommitUpdate();
        z.Close();
        BindGrid();
        Session["filenamezip"] = filenamezip;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SomeNameForThisScript", "window.open('DownloadZip.aspx', 'DownloadWindow','width=400,height=200');", true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Path.Combine()` instead of concatenation for `fpaths`:

```
string fpaths = Path.Combine(strPathAndQuery, filePath);
```

Also, make sure that when you pass `fpaths` or `filenamed` to `.Add(string, string)`, neither one is `null`.

Here's the source of the method you're trying to use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a file to the archive.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">The name of the file to add.</param>
/// <param name="entryName">The name to use for the <see cref="ZipEntry"/> on the Zip file created.</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Argument supplied is null.</exception>
public void Add(string fileName, string entryName)
{
    if (fileName == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
    }

    if ( entryName == null ) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entryName");
    }

    CheckUpdating();
    AddUpdate(new ZipUpdate(fileName, EntryFactory.MakeFileEntry(fileName, entryName, true)));
}
```

Since you're able to Add using `.Add(string)`, I suspect that you're passing a `null` to the overload you're trying to use.